# Hiding horizontal scroll bars without using overflow-x

Tags: css

If I set `overflow:scroll` for a div with fixed height, then both horizontal scroll and vertical scroll bars appears. I know that I can remove horizontal scroll bars by using `overflow-x:hidden`. Is there a way to do this without using overflow-x because it fails in css(2.1) validation?

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/s7SVZ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YOu can give `overflow:auto` to it. Write like this:

```
#div1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/s7SVZ/1/